# Django: How to force translation into a given language inside a template?

Tags: django, django-templates, internationalization, gettext

In a Django template, I need to transanlate some strings to a specific language (different from current one).

I would need something like this:

```
{% tans_to "de" "my string to translate" %}
or
{% blocktrans_to "de" %}my bloc to translate {% endblocktrans_to %}
```

to force translation to German.

I know I can call the following code in a view:

```
gettext.translation('django', 'locale', ['de'], fallback=True).ugettext("my string to translate")
```

Do I need to create a specific template tag ? Or does it already exist a dedicated tag in Django ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

templatetags/trans_to.py:

```
from django.utils import translation
from django.utils.translation import ugettext
from django.template import Library, Node,  Variable, TemplateSyntaxError
register = Library()

class TransNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, value, lc):
        self.value = Variable(value)
        self.lc = lc

    def render(self, context):        
        translation.activate(self.lc)
        val = ugettext(self.value.resolve(context))        
        translation.deactivate()        
        return val

def trans_to(parser, token):
    try:
        tag_name, value, lc = token.split_contents()
    except ValueError:
        raise TemplateSyntaxError, "%r tag requires arguments" % token.contents.split()[0]
    if not (lc[0] == lc[-1] and lc[0] in ('"', "'")):
        raise TemplateSyntaxError, "%r locale should be in quotes" % tag_name 
    return TransNode(value, lc[1:-1])

register.tag('trans_to', trans_to)
```

html:

```
{% load trans_to %}
{# pass string #}   
<p>{% trans_to "test" "de" %}</p>
<p>{% trans "test" %}</p>
{# pass variable #}
{% with "test" as a_variable %}
<p>{% trans_to a_variable "de" %}</p>
<p>{% trans a_variable %}</p>       
{% endwith %}
```

result:

```
<p>test in deutsch</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>test in deutsch</p>
<p>test</p>
```

Comment: Thanks zalew. I'll test it asap.

Comment: how's going? any bugs? like it?

Comment: cool. when I have some time, maybe will write the blocktrans version, too busy now. glad I helped.

Comment: Instead of runing `translation.activate` and then `translation.deactivate`, you can use the new `translation.override` context manager http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944260/247696

Answer (score 15):

From Django version `1.6`, there is a [`language`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/i18n/translation/#std:templatetag-language) template tag so you can simply pass the desired language code:

```
{% language "de" %}my block to translate{% endlanguage %}
```

Answer (score 3):

This a modified version of Zalew's code which allows template's variable for the locale parameter:

```
from django.utils import translation
from django.template import Library, Node,  Variable, TemplateSyntaxError
register = Library()

class TransNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, value, lc):
        self.value = Variable(value)
        self.lc =  Variable(lc)

    def render(self, context):
        translation.activate(self.lc.resolve(context))
        val = translation.ugettext(self.value.resolve(context))        
        translation.deactivate()
        return val

def trans_to(parser, token):
    """ 
    force translation into a given language
      usage : {% trans_to "string to translate" locale %}
    """
    try:
        tag_name, value, lc = token.split_contents()
    except ValueError:
            raise TemplateSyntaxError, '%r tag usage: {%% trans_to "string to translate" locale %%}' % token.contents.split()[0]
    return TransNode(value, lc)

register.tag('trans_to', trans_to)
```

Answer (score -3):

You could use the `trans` template tag inside your templates to translate strings to the desired language:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% trans "Hello" %}
```

You have to have `USE_I18N` set to `True` inside the `settings.py` file.

Then you define `LANGUAGE_CODE` to control the default language for the whole site and add the `LocaleMiddleware` class to your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`. Check out the [How Django Discovers Language Preference](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter19.html#how-django-discovers-language-preference) section from the documentation.

Comment: the_void, I know the "trans" tag. What I need is a way to change the current language for a specific string translation.