# Django switching, for a block of code, switch the language so translations are done in one language

Tags: python, django, internationalization, translation, gettext

I have a django project that uses a worker process that sends emails to users. The worker processes listens to a rabbitmq server and gets all the details about the email to send, the template variables, the email address to send to etc. The email body is created with django templates and [render_to_string](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#the-render-to-string-shortcut).

However I want to internationalize this. Some of our users are going to be using the website in English, some in other languages. They should get emails in their language. I have tried to i18n the email worker process (using django.utils.translations.ugettext/ugettext_lazy), so that the email subject and email body has [_(...)](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/internationalization/#standard-translation) or {% blocktrans %} resp.

However since the email is rendered and sent in a different background worker process, the normal [django language detection process](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/deployment/#how-django-discovers-language-preference) doesn't seem to apply. There is no user session, no cookies or no http headers for it to look at. When sending the message to the rabbitmq server, I can store the language code

**But** how do I tell django/gettext to use that language at a point.

e.g. My function that sends email might look like this:

```
def send_email(details):
  lang = details['lang']
  name = details['name']
  email_address = details['email_address']

  switch_gettext_to_this_language_what_goes_here(lang):
  # ?????
  email_subject = _("Welcome to $SITE")
```

What do I put in to switch django translations/gettext to a specific language code  so that the `_()` will use that language code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

simplest way to switch language is:

```
from django.utils.translation import activate
activate('en')
# do smthg
activate('pl')
# do something in other language
```

be carefull with this as it is changing context for the rest of the execution of this process/thread.

Comment: Note that `django.utils.translation` now have an `override(lang)` context manager that will automagically reset the original locale on exit.

Answer (score 48):

As @SteveMayne pointed out in comment (but it worth an answer), you can now use the context manager `translation.override` (works with Django 1.6, didn't check with earlier versions):

```
from django.utils import translation
print(_("Hello"))  # Will print to Hello if default = 'en'

# Make a block where the language will be Danish
with translation.override('dk'):
    print(_("Hello"))  # print "Hej"
```

It basically uses the same thing than @bitrut answer but it's built-in in Django, so it makes less dependencies...

Comment: it's present back all the way back to Django 1.4 at least!

Comment: override is more failsafe, because you dont have to think about setting the original language after doing your stuff!

Answer (score 15):

You can force language in a nice way using context manager:

```
class force_lang:
    def __init__(self, new_lang):
        self.new_lang = new_lang
        self.old_lang = translation.get_language()
    def __enter__(self):
       translation.activate(self.new_lang)
    def __exit__(self, type, value, tb):
       translation.activate(self.old_lang)
```

Then you can use `with` statement:

```
with force_lang('en'):
    ...
```

Comment: This is now included in the translation.override class.  `with translation.override('en'):`

Answer (score 5):

It's quite simple using `django-i18next` (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-i18next).

Load the templatetags.

```
{% load i18n i18next %}
```

The following code forces Dutch locale for whatever is put inside the `overridelocale` block.

```
{% overridelocale 'nl' %}
    <p>
        <a href="/login/">{% trans "Log in" %}</a>
    </p>
{% endoverridelocale %}
```

The following code forces Russian locale for whatever is put inside the `overridelocale` block.

```
{% overridelocale 'ru' %}
    <p>
        <a href="/login/">{% trans "Log in" %}</a>
    </p>
{% endoverridelocale %}
```

The following code forces English locale for whatever is put inside the `overridelocale` block.

```
{% overridelocale 'en' %}
    <p>
        <a href="/login/">{% trans "Log in" %}</a>
    </p>
{% endoverridelocale %}
```

Comment: There is a `{% language 'CODE' %}` template tag in django core: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/translation/#std:templatetag-language

Answer (score 1):

Turns out [the django docs explain how](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/i18n/#using-translations-outside-views-and-templates):

> While Django provides a rich set of i18n tools for use in views and templates, it does not restrict the usage to Django-specific code. The Django translation mechanisms can be used to translate arbitrary texts to any language that is supported by Django (as long as an appropriate translation catalog exists, of course). You can load a translation catalog, activate it and translate text to language of your choice, but remember to switch back to original language, as activating a translation catalog is done on per-thread basis and such change will affect code running in the same thread.

Comment: Yeah, just use `from django.utils import translation; translation.activate(language_code)`