# Django - Switch language setting for template rendering

Tags: django, internationalization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Django switching, for a block of code, switch the language so translations are done in one language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258715/django-switching-for-a-block-of-code-switch-the-language-so-translations-are-d)

Is there an easy way to get Django to switch language for a single template rendering operation?

In my case the user may trigger an event that will require to message a person that is not speaking the same language.

For instance - user is English speaker but invokes an action that messages a Spanish speaking person - thus I need to generate the outgoing content in Spanish language.

I am aware that it is possible by faking the Request and using RequestContext, however I would prefer a shorter/cleaner solution.

Comment: I'm not sure how Requests or RequestContexts come into this. Surely if user A sends user B a message, the message can simply be translated when user B requests to look at the message (depending on their language setting).

Comment: I was looking at: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1428/.

The issue is that I am sending an email or SMS message - thus the recipient never gets to interact with my Django app. However I have since learned that django.utils.translate.activate/deactivate is the correct answer as shanyu has pointed out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you looking for something like the following:

```
from django.utils import translation
language_code = 'xx'
template_body = Template(some_text_var)
translation.activate(language_code)
r = template_body.render(context)
translation.deactivate()
```

For better code reuse, you can refactor this as a context manager.

Comment: using context manager - http://stackoverflow.com/a/10385085/486209