# How to format date in different languages?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a Django project with settings set to lang 'pl', in every template I use localized date format, for example:

```
{{ item.date|date:'D, d N H:i:s e' }}

result:
    Wt, 13 Lis 2012 22:00:00
```

But in only one template I must use format for lang 'en':

```
Thu, 13 Nov 2012 22:00:00 GMT
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried the `unlocalize` template filter (with `{% load l10n %}`)? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/i18n/localization/#template-filters

Comment: No, this not work, maybe because ulocalize set locale to server locales which is set to 'pl'... I don't know. {% localize off %} also not work

Comment: This answer can resolve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853906/django-switch-language-setting-for-template-rendering

Answer (score 23):

This helps for me:

```
{% load i18n %}

{% language 'en' %}
  {{ item.date|date:'D, d N H:i:s e' }}
{% endlanguage %}
```

For more details, see the Django online [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#switching-language-in-templates).

Comment: Still works in 2020, don't forget the {% load i18n %} tag

Answer (score 2):

This help for me, in that view where I use lang 'en' and load template:

```
from django.conf import settings

settings.LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'
settings.USE_L10N = False
settings.USE_I18N = False
```

Comment: It's never a good idea to modify the global settings like this.  Django provides `translation.override()` to set a language context within a view.