# gettext for specific locales

Tags: python, django, internationalization

I can get the translation in current locale using.

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
_("password")
```

However in my code (a form to be specific) I want to get the translation in a specific language. I want to be able to say.

```
ugettext_magic("de", "password")
```

I already have the strings translated in the languages I need.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3176213/462865

Answer (score 21):

Context manager [django.utils.translation.override](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.override) activates a new language on enter and reactivates the previous active language on exit

```
from django.utils import translation

def get_translation_in(language, s):
    with translation.override(language):
        return translation.gettext(s)

print(get_translation_in('de', 'text'))
```

Comment: This answer is to be prefered to the answer with more upvotes imho. It does not play around with activating and deactivating translations which lead to troubles in my code and is an elegant solution to the problem.

Answer (score 10):

There is a workaround:

```
from django.utils import translation
from django.utils.translation import ugettext

def get_translation_in(string, locale):
    translation.activate(locale)
    val = ugettext(string)
    translation.deactivate()

print get_translation_in('text', 'de')
```

Or simply:

```
gettext.translation('django', 'locale', ['de'], fallback=True).ugettext('text')
```

Comment: if you had already set the locale previously ... does this wipe that out? Ive never seen this ... cool though

Comment: in Python 3 use: `gettext.translation('django', 'locale', ['de'], fallback=True).gettext('text')` it will always return unicode